# Compactification of additional dimensions

Tags: string-theory, spacetime-dimensions, compactification

The extra dimensions in string theory are supposed to close in on themselves to form circles. Are there other possibilities for compactification? For example a compactification in segment.

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/600618/2451

Comment: They don’t form circles. I’m fairly sure that that compactification doesn’t work. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calabi–Yau_manifold#Applications_in_superstring_theory) for what might.